# Head Scratcher: Mini Split Conduit Question

Tags: electrical, air-conditioning, conduit, mini-split

I'm installing a Mr Cool 24K BTU DIY mini split 240v system. It's replacing one that worked flawlessly for 2 years. The manufacturer replaced my original one because of a manufacturing defect - refrigerant leak that could not be identified. Super legit of the company so I'm a fan for life.

Anyway the new system is a generation 3 with some nice enhancements. Because of the differences I studied the install manual front to back and something caught my eye. The signal cable connects the indoor unit to the outdoor unit. The manual states to run it in conduit along side the refrigerant lines. Here's where I'm scratching my head.

I'm thinking OK "signal cable", low voltage possibly DC different codes so I can run it in a raceway (lineset cover) and forgo the conduit. The lineset cover runs horizontally from the indoor unit (7' high) around a corner before dropping behind the outside unit sitting 4' off the ground (flood zone).

As I'm hooking everything up I realize there's 4 conductors in the signal cable? OK, I pull my meter out and find (2) 120v on the cable with neutral and ground. So I have (2) 120V instead of 240V as I have a neutral?

It's a heat pump so no heat strip why the 120V, the only thing requiring any sort of high current is the blower fan. But now that it's high voltage it needs to be in conduit and not just the lineset covers even though they're elevated? And, if I have to run it in conduit, would 1/2" flex non-metalic be acceptable?

I'm not sure how or where to put the liquid tight fitting near the indoor unit as it goes through the exterior wall and the lineset has already been uncoiled and routed making removal of the indoor unit impossible. Also, what about drainage?

Comment: The Gen3 MrCool units run their signal cable in with the lineset.  Can you provide us with any writing or printing on the jacket of said cable?

Comment: 120V times two is how US 240V is distributed.  They are phased opposite, so both 120V to ground and 240V between.  Neutral may not even be involved.